# Web navigation with dark color schemes

Tags: kde, colors, web

I use KDE with a dark color scheme so the text main color is white. Unfortunately this causes many websites to be unusable because text inside combobox, checkbox, and similar inherits the white color and so is white, while the background does not inherits the black color from the color scheme so is again white. So you have white on white.

I use firefox as my main browser but this happens also in chromium and rekonq.

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered what I think is a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/256089/25656). *I have copy-pasted most of the answer from there below. I don't know if it is ethical to do. Apologies in advance if it isn't. If it isn't the right thing to do , I'll delete it.*

The following deals with Firefox, but the relevant code should be usable in Google Chrome when placed in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User Stylesheets/Custom.css`. For Chromium, look in `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/`. I have no knowledge about the third browser.

Close (exit) all instances of Firefox.
Go to your profile folder. It is here: `/home/your_name/.mozilla/firefox/randomstring.default`. In there, look for a subfolder called `chrome`.
If it doesn't exist, create it.
To create the `chrome` folder you can use your file manager (or the command line with `mkdir chrome`).
If `chrome` does exist, look for a file called `userContent.css`. Otherwise, create an empty text file with this name in the `chrome` folder.
Now open `userContent.css` with a text editor and paste in or append this code:

```
INPUT, TEXTAREA {color: black !important; background: #aaaaaa !important; }
```

Save the file (as plain text) and close the text editor.
Restart Firefox.
You should now have black text on a light gray background. You can use whatever color combination you prefer.

Notes: `chrome` and `userContent.css` are case-sensitive and should be spelled correctly. The settings here will take precedence over those in the OS theme and will remain the same in Firefox irrespective of which `gtk` theme you switch to.

Comment: (What you write belongs to you. You're free to post it anywhere you want, and there's no ethical problems at all. Posting the same answer on the same site is frowned up - it's better to close the questions as duplicate. But there's no cross-site duplicate close option.)

Comment: unfortunately I can't vote you answer up...